# How to parse data from a json with multiple same array objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello am trying to use json_decode to decode a json object with multiple same   arrays

I have tried Json _decode to access member elements but am receiving blank details

```
$json_string =file_get_contents('php://input');

  $date='19/08/2019';
  $time_rec='9:07 pm';
  $device=$json_string['ident'];
  $imei=$json_string['ident'];
  $speed=$json_string['position.speed'];
  $longitude=$json_string['position.longitude'];
  $latitudedirection=$json_string['position.direction'];
  $latitude=$json_string['position.latitude'];
  $ain1=$json_string['ain.1'];
  $ignition=$json_string['engine.ignition.status'];
  $voltage=$json_string['external.powersource.voltage'];
  $signaldis='0';
  $powerdis='0';
  $brand='PGL';
  $car_plate='KCL 364V';
/*
```

Json element i receive looks like

```
[
{"ain.1":8.279,
"channel.id":12192,
"custom.param.329":68,
"device.id":388228,
"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER",
"device.type.id":102,
"engine.ignition.status":true,
"event.enum":0,
"event.priority.enum":0,
"external.powersource.voltage":19.69,
"gnss.status":true,
"ident":"358480088504651",
"peer":"197.182.172.51:63370",
"position.altitude":0,
"position.latitude":-1.277276,
"position.longitude":36.829203,
"position.speed":0,
"position.valid":false,
"protocol.id":14,
"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,
"timestamp":1566241439
},
{"ain.1":8.315,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":0,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.69,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241444
},
{"ain.1":8.169,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.648,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241449
},
{"ain.1":8.033,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.67,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241454
},
{"ain.1":7.767,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.674,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241459
}
]
```

i need to parse data only for the first array element only

Comment: Where is the `json_decode($json_string);` that you need to use to convert a JSONString into a PHP data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert the JSON String into a PHP data type using `json_decode()`.

```
<?php

$in = '[
        {"ain.1":8.279,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,
        "device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER",
        "device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,
        "event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.69,
        "gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651",
        "peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,
        "position.latitude":-1.277276,"position.longitude":36.829203,
        "position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,
        "protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,
        "timestamp":1566241439
        },
        {"ain.1":8.315,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":0,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.69,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241444
        },
        {"ain.1":8.169,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.648,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241449
        },
        {"ain.1":8.033,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.67,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241454
        },
        {"ain.1":7.767,"channel.id":12192,"custom.param.329":68,"device.id":388228,"device.name":"PGL SPEED LIMITER","device.type.id":102,"engine.ignition.status":true,"event.enum":0,"event.priority.enum":0,"external.powersource.voltage":19.674,"gnss.status":true,"ident":"358480088504651","peer":"197.182.172.51:63370","position.altitude":0,"position.latitude":-1.277175,"position.longitude":36.829066,"position.speed":0,"position.valid":false,"protocol.id":14,"server.timestamp":1566241472.410389,"timestamp":1566241459
        }
        ]';

$json = json_decode($in);

$device=$json[0]->ident;
echo $device.PHP_EOL;

$speed=$json[0]->{'position.speed'};
echo $speed.PHP_EOL;

$longitude=$json[0]->{'position.longitude'};
echo $longitude .  PHP_EOL;
```